# How to have numerous text items on one layer in Gimp?

Tags: gimp, layers, text

I'm making a map in Gimp. I want to have the following layers:

1. background
2. cities
3. rivers
4. mountains

So I want, say, 30 cities on one layer so that I can turn it off and on. However, every time I create a new text item, it creates a new layer.

How can I put numerous text items on one layer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can either merge your text layers into one layer (select a text layer and use the merge down menu item http://docs.gimp.org/nl/gimp-layer-merge-down.html) which will combine it with the layer below.

Alternatively, instead of having one layer for all your text, you could group all your text layers into a master 'text' layer (http://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-layer-groups.html).

Comment: Just to clarify (so it's crystal clear to anyone else trying to figure this out), you *cannot* have multiple texts in a single layer in the current version of GIMP. You need to merge the text layers (which will discard the text information) or use a layer group (which is what I prefer).

Answer (score 0):

My take is that each object in Gimp has it's own layer. That is the only way they can be modified without altering all of them at once. I don't know if putting all items in one layer is the same as grouping them, but certainly, they are easier to manipulate when they are in their own layer.

Comment: This does not really answer this old question, it's mostly your opinion on the subject. Wait until you have enough reputation to post comments (20) and only use the Answer button to post a constructive answer to the question. There are many other unanswered questions that would benefit from a good answer, perhaps you could contribute!

Answer (score 0):

I would make your current layers into layer groups, and name them appropriately (e.g. "Cities"). This is available as of GIMP 2.8.

Then add either add the existing (text) layers to the groups, or create new ones in them. As long as the group or a layer within it is active when you create a new (text) layer, this will happen automatically. For existing layers, drag&frop in the layers dialog is a quick way to add them to a group.